# compile vs implementation in gradle | Getting NoClassDefFound when using in implementation in gradle

Tags: gradle, compilation, noclassdeffounderror, implementation

I am running a subProcess in java ,
when using "implementation" in gradle I am getting NoClassDefFound for com/azure/core/management/AzureEnvironment, but when I am using in compile everything is working fine

why is it working for compile but not for implementation ?

When I will use it in implementation for subProcess I expect it will without any error of: NoClassDefFound
but i am getting this error:   NoClassDefFound for com/azure/core/management/AzureEnvironment

Comment: `compile` is deprecated and removed in Gradle 7+. What's your gradle version?

Comment: the version is: 5.4.1